# Multiple Background Images using Sass / Compass

Tags: css, base64, sencha-touch, sass, compass-sass

The following generates a base64 inline-image using sass/compass:

```
background-image:inline-image("paper.jpg", 'image/jpg');
```

Is there a way to do multiple background images, or do I have to precompress them myself to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The inline-image function just outputs the url() string, so you can use multiple by doing this:

```
background: inline-image("front-image.jpg", 'image/jpg') no-repeat, inline-image("back-image.jpg", 'image/jpg') repeat-x
```

And you'll get the following css:

```
background: url('data:"image/jpg";base64,FRONTIMAGEDATAHERE') no-repeat, url('data:"image/jpg";base64,BACKIMAGEDATAHERE') repeat-x;
```

I added "no-repeat" and "repeat-x" otherwise the front-image will repeat and cover the back-image.

Comment: Note that if you wish to apply a background color when using the `background` shorthand, [it is only permitted in the final layer](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background): `Note that a color is permitted in <final-bg-layer>, but not in <bg-layer>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm use sencha touch 2 and found next sass extension for this:

**theme_images.rb:**

```
module SenchaTouch
  module SassExtensions
    module Functions
      module ThemeImages
        def theme_image(theme, path, mime_type = nil)
          path = path.value
          images_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "..", "images", theme.value)
          real_path = File.join(images_path, path)
          inline_image_string(data(real_path), compute_mime_type(path, mime_type))
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

module Sass::Script::Functions
  include SenchaTouch::SassExtensions::Functions::ThemeImages
end
```

**compass_init.rb:**

```
# This file registers the sencha-touch framework with compass
# It's a magic name that compass knows how to find.
dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
require File.join(dir, 'lib', 'theme_images.rb')

Compass::Frameworks.register 'sencha-touch', dir
```

See usages:

```
background: theme_image($theme-name, "clear_icon.png") no-repeat;
-webkit-mask: theme_image($theme-name, "select_mask.png");
-webkit-mask-image: theme_image($theme-name, "pictos/arrow_down.png");
```